# Basketball game

Tags: java, game

I have many lines of code that - to me - look very odd, and I would like to condense, but I don't exactly know how.
This is the part I dislike the most:

```
if(random.nextInt(50) == 26) {
    int rnteam = random.nextInt(twoteams.size());
    String rndteam = "";
    if(rnteam == 0) rndteam = team1.getName();
    else if(rnteam == 1) rndteam = team2.getName();
    String rndplayfrndteam = "";
    int rndplayer = random.nextInt(5);
    if(rndteam == team1.getName()) rndplayfrndteam = team1.getPlayers().get(rndplayer);
    else if(rndteam == team2.getName()) rndplayfrndteam = team2.getPlayers().get(rndplayer);
    // Determining this player's score
    // Team 1
    if(rndplayfrndteam == team1.getPlayers().get(0)) t1p1score += scoreAmount;
    if(rndplayfrndteam == team1.getPlayers().get(1)) t1p2score += scoreAmount;
    if(rndplayfrndteam == team1.getPlayers().get(2)) t1p3score += scoreAmount;
    if(rndplayfrndteam == team1.getPlayers().get(3)) t1p4score += scoreAmount;
    if(rndplayfrndteam == team1.getPlayers().get(4)) t1p5score += scoreAmount;
    // Team 2
    if(rndplayfrndteam == team2.getPlayers().get(0)) t2p1score += scoreAmount;
    if(rndplayfrndteam == team2.getPlayers().get(1)) t2p2score += scoreAmount;
    if(rndplayfrndteam == team2.getPlayers().get(2)) t2p3score += scoreAmount;
    if(rndplayfrndteam == team2.getPlayers().get(3)) t2p4score += scoreAmount;
    if(rndplayfrndteam == team2.getPlayers().get(4)) t2p5score += scoreAmount;

    if(rnteam == 0) {
        t1sofar += scoreAmount;
    } else {
        t2sofar += scoreAmount;
    }
    int[] t1scores = {t1p1score, t1p2score, t1p3score, t1p4score, t1p5score};
    int t1maxScore = findGreatestInt(t1scores);
    int t1bestPlayer = 0;
    if(t1maxScore == t1p1score) t1bestPlayer = 1;
    if(t1maxScore == t1p2score) t1bestPlayer = 2;
    if(t1maxScore == t1p3score) t1bestPlayer = 3;
    if(t1maxScore == t1p4score) t1bestPlayer = 4;
    if(t1maxScore == t1p5score) t1bestPlayer = 5;

    int[] t2scores = {t2p1score, t2p2score, t2p3score, t2p4score, t2p5score};
    int t2maxScore = findGreatestInt(t2scores);
    int t2bestPlayer = 0;
    if(t2maxScore == t2p1score) t2bestPlayer = 1;
    if(t2maxScore == t2p2score) t2bestPlayer = 2;
    if(t2maxScore == t2p3score) t2bestPlayer = 3;
    if(t2maxScore == t2p4score) t2bestPlayer = 4;
    if(t2maxScore == t2p5score) t2bestPlayer = 5;
    hangOver(rndplayfrndteam + " scored " + scoreAmount, team1, team2, t1bestPlayer, t1maxScore, t2bestPlayer, t2maxScore, t1sofar, t2sofar);
} else {
    int[] t1scores = {t1p1score, t1p2score, t1p3score, t1p4score, t1p5score};
    int t1maxScore = findGreatestInt(t1scores);
    int t1bestPlayer = 0;
    if(t1maxScore == t1p1score) t1bestPlayer = 1;
    if(t1maxScore == t1p2score) t1bestPlayer = 2;
    if(t1maxScore == t1p3score) t1bestPlayer = 3;
    if(t1maxScore == t1p4score) t1bestPlayer = 4;
    if(t1maxScore == t1p5score) t1bestPlayer = 5;

    int[] t2scores = {t2p1score, t2p2score, t2p3score, t2p4score, t2p5score};
    int t2maxScore = findGreatestInt(t2scores);
    int t2bestPlayer = 0;
    if(t2maxScore == t2p1score) t2bestPlayer = 1;
    if(t2maxScore == t2p2score) t2bestPlayer = 2;
    if(t2maxScore == t2p3score) t2bestPlayer = 3;
    if(t2maxScore == t2p4score) t2bestPlayer = 4;
    if(t2maxScore == t2p5score) t2bestPlayer = 5;
    hangOver("No one", team1, team2, t1bestPlayer, t1maxScore, t2bestPlayer, t2maxScore, t1sofar, t2sofar);
}
```

All of the if-statements combined just look bad, and aren't very efficient. Is there a way I could change these into a loop and it still work? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my comments in order of severity:

### 1) BUGS

1. Test equality of Strings using `equals()` not `==`
2. use of `else if`
   let's examine this piece of code

   `String rndteam = "";`
   `if(rnteam == 0) rndteam = team1.getName();`
   `else if(rnteam == 1) rndteam = team2.getName();`

it assigns a value to the String `rndteam`.  now, I assume that the logic was meant that `rndteam` should be assigned the name of either `team1` or `team2` but the code actually allows for both `if` statements to be false and the value will then be an empty String. You can fix that by changing the flow to an `if else` one

```
String rndteam = "";   
if(rnteam == 0) rndteam = team1.getName();     
else rndteam = team2.getName();
```

in my eyes, in the case of deciding between two options, the short form of the if statement can be used to make it clear:

```
String rndteam = rnteam == 0 ? team1.getName() : team2.getName();
```

### 2) Design problems

1. Now we come to the question of all those `if` statements. You already have arrays that you assign the variables into so why not use them when you ask about the team players?

   `int[] t1scores = new int[team1.size()];`
   `for (int i = 0 ; i < team1.size(); i++) {`
   `if(rndplayfrndteam.equals(team1.getPlayers().get(i))) t1scores[i] += scoreAmount;`
   `}`
2. But really, as it was already suggested, you should design a class that holds  all the information of a Player and another for team.

Comment: Why are you saying `team1.size()`? The team class has no size() method. Just `getPlayers(),` `getName(),` and `getWin/LosAm` as well as `setWin/LosAm`

Comment: probably meant `team1.getPlayers().size()`

Answer (score 2):

Once you have a number of variables with similar names, such as `t?p?score`, you should consider changing these to arrays (a 2D one would make sense in your case), which you can then iterate over in a loop to reduce the repetition.

What is so special about the `if(random.nextInt(50) == 26)` condition?  Some constants would be useful here.

Try to avoid removing letters from variable names just to shorten them, lest they lose their meaning.  I can't work out what `rndplayfrndteam` means.

A method called `hangOver` tells me absolutely nothing about what it does, and you should consider a different name.

You may wish to consider some data classes to keep the players and their scores together, possibly including their teams as well, to keep things a bit cleaner.

Comment: BTW: `rndplayfrndteam` is random player from random team. `if(random.nextInt(50) == 26)` is how I check: "score? or not?" I had it set to `if(random.nextInt(50) == random.nextInt(50))`

Comment: This would have been clearer: `boolean didScore = random.nextInt(50) == 26; if (didScore) { ... } else { ... }`